# How to get generated ID after inserting new record in database table using Spring JDBCTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbc

I know that this is an duplicated question but the other solutions on the other pages isn't working for me.

I have a Oracle database and I want to fetch inserted record ID (primary key) but I'm unable to do so. Below is the error and my code.

> org.springframework.dao.DataRetrievalFailureException: The generated
>   key is not of a supported numeric type. Unable to cast
>   [oracle.sql.ROWID] to [java.lang.Number]

```
String query = "INSERT INTO JOBS (USERNAME, CREATED_ON, STATUS, JOBTYPE, DATA) " + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

try {

 KeyHolder holder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();

 jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {

  @Override
  public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
   PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
   ps.setString(1, "username");
   ps.setTimestamp(2, new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
   ps.setString(3, "status");
   ps.setString(4, "jobtype");
   ps.setString(5, "job-data");

   return ps;
  }
 }, holder);
 System.out.println("Holder tostring: " + holder.toString());
 System.out.println("Ran an update statement and got generated key. Key = " + holder.getKey().intValue());
 System.out.println("Key: " + holder.getKey().longValue());
 return true;
} catch (DataAccessException e) {
 System.err.println("Exception thrown inserting record into table. Error: " + e.getMessage());
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I run the app in debug mode I'm seeing holder variable keyList value is: `[{ROWID=AAAKy2AAAAALRgdAAD}]` I'm not getting the inserted record Id.

Create table script is:

```
CREATE TABLE JOBS (
    ID          INTEGER                 GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1),
    USERNAME    VARCHAR2(20)            NOT NULL,
    CREATEDON   TIMESTAMP               NOT NULL,
    STATUS      VARCHAR2(10)            NOT NULL,
    JOBTYPE     VARCHAR2(15)             NOT NULL,
    DATA        VARCHAR2(1000 CHAR)     NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);
```

Comment: change ID from INTEGER to NUMBER and you should be using sequence for the ID. I don't think oracle uses INTEGER as data_type, unless you define those on your own in the database as custom data_type

Comment: Hi @logger, I changed my Jobs table ID to Number and removed Generated Always ... and created sequence for generating ID's and trigger on insert command to add ID value on insert command. Still I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `con.prepareStatement(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)`, the Oracle JDBC driver will not return the value of the `id` column, but instead it will return the ROW_ID (a pseudo column that identifies a specific row), to allow you to retrieve the value yourself.

Historically the Oracle driver did it this way, because previous Oracle versions didn't have identity columns.

Instead you should use:

```
con.prepareStatement(query, new String[] { "ID" });
```

Which instructs Oracle to return the value of the specified column.