# Insert into Oracle table using PutSQL returns rowid value for sql.generated.key attribute instead of generated sequence id

Tags: oracle, plsql, apache-nifi

We are trying to insert records into Oracle table using `PutSQL` and attribute `Obtain Generated Keys` is set to `true`. NiFi `DBCPConnectionPool` controller service is configured to use `Oracle 12c` and JDBC is `ojdbc8.jar`.

The expected value for attribute `sql.generated.key` should be in number but getting `rowid` like `AAJV6hAAAAAB/qFAAA`.

So do we need to do any config settings at Oracle end to return the generated sequence id instead of `rowid`?

Please note that the same is working as expected for PostgreSQL!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47098003/how-to-get-generated-id-after-inserting-new-record-in-database-table-using-sprin),

> the Oracle JDBC driver will not return the value of the id column, but instead it will return the ROW_ID (a pseudo column that identifies a specific row), to allow you to retrieve the value yourself.

> Historically the Oracle driver did it this way, because previous Oracle versions didn't have identity columns.

So I have to add a processor to get the generated sequence ID from `rowid`.